# Can not establish connection to SOAP WebService after WSDL2Java Axis

Tags: java, web-services, soap, connection

I have a problem to connect to an existing WebService (SOAP) through Java generated files from WSDL2Java tool from Axis 1.4.

I've automatically generated the following Java files:

```
ILIASSoapWebservice.java
ILIASSoapWebserviceBindingStub.java
ILIASSoapWebserviceLocator.java
ILIASSoapWebservicePortType.java
IlOperation.java
IlUserData.java
```

And now, I can't establish any connection.
How to achieve this to call the RPC's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already generated the Stubs, you can use the `ILIASSoapWebserviceLocator` to get a reference to the service and then invoke the operations on the service via the stub.

```
ILIASSoapWebserviceLocator service = new ILIASSoapWebserviceLocator();
URL portAddress = new URL("http://host:port/yourWebservice" );
ILIASSoapWebservicePortType stub = service.getILIASSoapWebservicePort(portAddress);
stub.<operations>();
```

You can find [here](http://www.digizol.com/2008/07/web-service-axis-tutorial-client-server.html) a complete server side and client side web service implementation tutorial on Axis 1.4.

Comment: @Ikamal And what is "YourStub"?

Comment: @Ikamal: I don't have a method which returns a "ILIASSoapWebservice" only getIliasSoapWebservicePort...()

Comment: @MarcelHöll I used the <YourStub> and <operations> since those details are not visible to me from the .java file names you have listed. 

Can you give more details so that I can help here? 

What is the return type of getIliasSoapWebservicePort...() method?

Comment: @Ikamal The following methods are listed:
getILIASSoapWebservicePortAddress():String
getILIASSoapWebservicePortWSDDServiceName():String
getILIASSoapWebservicePort():ILIASSoapWebservicePortType
getPort():Remote
getServiceName():QName

Comment: @MarcelHöll I have updated the answer based on the above method list. Can you see whether it resolves the issue.

Comment: @Ikamal: Now i get the following error if calling a method:
{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect

Comment: @MarcelHöll Now the issue is with connecting to the service. Instead of using getILIASSoapWebservicePort() can you try using getILIASSoapWebservicePort(URL) with the correct URL of the web service.

Comment: @Ikamal: Thank you now it is working correct. But I need to have some time to get the different method meanings for my client application ;)

Comment: @MarcelHöll Great, since it is working hopefully you can play around to find more info.